Store Data From Confluent Kafka in GCP Bucket
I have an issue with Confluent Kafka Terraform GCP configuration.
Goal:
Establish an infrastructure with confluent kafka that populates a GCP bucket.
Approach:

I am using basic-kafka-acl configuration provided by Terraform (I adapted the example to GCP and validated that it is working properly): Terraform example
Next step would be involved in adding GCP storage sink connector to configuration (I guess), is that the right approach? Should I consider a different approach?

Unfortunately I wasn't able to find and example for this case or a proper documentation for valid attributes and their values.
Here is current configuration snippet (which doesn't work):
resource "google_storage_bucket" "gcs_bucket" {
  name          = "my-topic-bucket"
  location      = var.region
  project       = var.project
  force_destroy = true

  uniform_bucket_level_access = true
}


resource "confluent_connector" "sink" {
  environment {
    id = confluent_environment.environment.id
  }
  kafka_cluster {
    id = confluent_kafka_cluster.basic.id
  }

  config_sensitive = {
    "gcs.credentials.config" = file("${path.module}/google_keys/sa.json")
  }

  config_nonsensitive = {
    "connector.class"      = "io.confluent.connect.gcs.GcsSinkConnector"
    "name"                 = "GCS_SINKConnector_0"
    "tasks.max"            = "1"
    "topics"               = "my-topic"
    "gcs.bucket.name"      = "my-topic-bucket"
    "gcs.part.size"        = "5242880"
    "flush.size"           = "1000"
    "storage.class"        = "io.confluent.connect.gcs.storage.GcsStorage"
    "format.class"         = "io.confluent.connect.gcs.format.avro.AvroFormat"
    "schema.compatibility" = "NONE"
    "output.data.format"   = "AVRO"
    "time.interval"        = "HOURLY"
  }

  lifecycle {
    prevent_destroy = true
  }

  depends_on = [
    google_storage_bucket.gcs_bucket
  ]
}

